# How to add a gallery in photologue?

Tags: python, django, photologue

I installed photologue correctly in my project (blog) and I can add images in admin panel, but how to display them on my main page?

Answer (score 0):

In the admin panel, you also need to:

1. Create a gallery.
2. Choose which photos are a part of which galleries.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my projects, I created a product model had a foreign key linked to a Gallery:

```
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, blank=True, related_name='gallery')
```

The issue in the template is that you cannot iterate over a Gallery or Photo from Photologue. I had to call `product.gallery.photos.all()` in order to iterate over the collection of images in my gallery.

To get the url of the image to link to the `src` of an `<img>` tag, you can just run (if you're iterating):

```
    for image in product.gallery.photos.all():
        {{ image.url }}
```

Hope this helps!